# Native DirectX, Basic Effect(.fx) Workflow

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, directx, effect

I have used hlsl effects before in XNA, but now I am trying to use them in C++ with DirectX9 and am confused about some points:

1. In XNA you can have the .fx file present in the solution explorer, is this how it is done in C++ too? As I was having some difficulty adding the fx file. Or do you just put everything in a folder in the project dir. and just browse it from windows explorer?
2. I have the following C++ code to load the effect:

`ID3DXEffect* g_pEffect = NULL;

DWORD dwShaderFlags = 0;

    dwShaderFlags |= D3DXSHADER_FORCE_VS_SOFTWARE_NOOPT;

    dwShaderFlags |= D3DXSHADER_FORCE_PS_SOFTWARE_NOOPT;

    dwShaderFlags |= D3DXSHADER_NO_PRESHADER;

    // Read the D3DX effect file

    WCHAR str[MAX_PATH];

    DXUTFindDXSDKMediaFileCch( str, MAX_PATH, L"BasicHLSL.fx" );

    D3DXCreateEffectFromFile( pd3dDevice, str, NULL, NULL, dwShaderFlags, NULL, &g_pEffect, NULL );`

But the types and functions aren't being recognised/found, so I'm thinking I'm missing an #include (currently I only have d3d9.h)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When creating the effect from the file, just give it the relative path to the file from your working directory. There is no need to bundle it into your application if you don't want.
2. You must also #include d3dx9.h (and reference the associated d3dx9.lib). Effect handling, 3D math (vectors and matrices), and a few other things are handling by D3DX. They aren't absolutely required to use D3D, so they are kept in a separate library.

Comment: I get this error: LNK1104: cannot open file 'd3dx9.lib'. I have added the lib to the 'additional dependencies' string in the project properties, is there something else I need to do?